# How to pass an argument to a hook without creating a custom module?

Tags: hooks

I need to attach a theme-agnostic ("global") CSS file to the `preprocess_hook()` function so that any theme I use, would include that CSS.

I want to do that without creating a custom module because while I am a programmer, I am just not a PHP programmer and I find the documentation about creating custom modules overkill for this specific goal and I won't learn this entire subject just for a CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, you can't use hooks without writing a custom module.

The [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module provides a UI to access some hooks without writing code, but this is mostly limited to entity-related hooks (add, delete, update / CRUD operations).

**Custom modules aren't that hard**

Custom modules can be as little as ~10 lines of code; they are not hard to write.  However, the [core documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules) is quite thorough and difficult to skim; it may be more information than what you need.

In that case, I recommend beginner-friendly (but paid) tutorials like [module development with Drupalize.me](https://drupalize.me/series/module-development-guide).

Comment: It's not about hard or not, it's about expertise; I am a programmer, just not a PHP programmer (maybe I should edit to clarify) and does not mean to learn the entire subject just for a CSS file.

Comment: You have made a wrong assumption that these are hard due to being "written for programmers"; I tell you as a programmer (I can refer you to my GitHub account to go through some Bash, JavaScript and even PHP codes I wrote if you don't believe me that I am a programmer) that my problem is at least one of these reasons: **1)** My native language is not English and not Germanic, **2)** I have a hard time reading such long English texts from a computer screen, **3)** I feel bad doing things I grasp as reserved for experts. In essence, I think you should edit the answer.

Comment: Here is a referral, just in case: https://github.com/bendqh1?tab=repositories

Comment: @Alkalix Ok, well the mechanism Drupal provides for using hooks is modules.  So the answer to your question **How to pass an argument to a hook without creating a module?** is no, you can't.  However, a custom module, as noted in my answer, can be as little as 10 lines of code and can be created in less than a minute with any text editor.  Creating a custom module does not require learning a bunch of Drupal APIs; basically, you create a `mymodule.info.yml` (not PHP! just YML), and then you add your custom hook code and you are done.

Comment: My main problem is with the saying `However, the core documentation is written for programmers so it may be difficult to understand the documentation.` which I find misleading and I think should be edited. Hardness with the documentation doesn't necessarily do with being a programmer or not, at least from my life experience.

Comment: @Alkalix That's a fair point; I updated my answer.